How can I fix this issue and generate an APK using Python and Flet?

I attempted to build a release version of what I thought was my Flutter app for Android, but the process is failing. Here's some background:

I'm using PyCharm Community Edition.
The code was written using Python and Flet, not Flutter. I generated the code with ChatGPT and Claude.ai, and I have a basic understanding of coding.
I do not have Android Studio installed.

When i convert to exe, its works perfectly.

When i run this my local its working, when i convert to apk. its show some err....   link

You need Android Studio installed inorder to build an APK.
I suggest you follow the Flutter documentation and properly install Flutter and all the required stuffs: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install
(when you are done, run flutter doctor to make sure everything is OK)
